# Dell Vostro 3560: 3NB8W3 battery not recognized, problems with charging

Tags: windows-7, power-supply, battery, dell-vostro

I've been using standard battery for a while, but finally I bought extended battery (3NB8W3, 11.1v 8700mAh 97Wh). Sadly, my Vostro 3560 does not recognize battery properly.

I always have "Plugged in and charging" icon in tray when I plug power adapter. When I unplug it, I get empty battery icon without information about power level.

[image]

Besides that battery works fine (about 4-5h), but:

- It is not charging when I plug in power adapter when computer is suspended (charging icon suggests it's charging, but it's not, at least not always)
- when it's completely discharged I have to plug in power adapter (while I'm logged in to Windows), then remove battery and install it again; then repeat this again later because it will only charge about 50% without it

I did what I found about ACPI driver (uninstall, restart computer etc), but it does not work. BIOS updated to latest version.

From Dell Support Center:

[image]

From BatteryMon:

[image]

I have tried resetting like [here](https://www.ncconsumer.org/news-articles/resetting-a-dell-laptop-battery-in-five-quick-steps.html) but it did not work too.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I recently went to replace my Dell Vostro 3560 battery with a higher capacity after market one. It appears to be a problem for a number of people, that the battery is not recognised, and wont charge. 
This happened with me. I tried everything I could get my hands on, from the internet, to fix it, no avail.
What solved it, was I powered the machine down, took the power cord out, took the battery out, then put the battery back in again and booted the machine up without the power cord attached - the boot was off the battery itself, and seemed to resolve the problem.
My wife and I have identical machines, so I bought another battery for my one and had exactly the same problem, but was resolved in using exactly the same method I describe above.

Hope this help someone else who is tearing their hair out.